# How to forget the contents of all Firefox tabs (releasing RAM), and refreashing a tab to re-access site when needed?

Tags: firefox, memory, cache, browser-tabs, browser-cache

I want to run a game but my RAM is full and I can't close my Firefox windows due to needing them later for my workflow.

So I'm wondering, is it possible to tell Firefox to simply forget every site it has in RAM but keep the tabs in place? And then I can re-access any site by refreshing its tab?

Comment: Does [Unload inactive tabs to save system memory in Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/unload-inactive-tabs-save-system-memory-firefox) answer you question?

Comment: Or [Auto Tab Discard](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/auto-tab-discard/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some source of memory bloat in Firefox are inefficient extensions, so
removing unrequired extensions could help.

The internal mechanism in Firefox to free memory is :

- Enter `about:memory` in the address field
- Click on "Minimize memory usage".

The description of this button is :

> Send three "heap-minimize" notifications in a row. Each notification
> triggers a global garbage collection followed by a cycle collection,
> and causes the process to reduce memory usage in other ways, e.g.
> by f‌lushing various caches.

You could click this button before running the game, in order for
Firefox to minimize its used memory.

You can analyze your memory use in this screen by using the
"Show memory reports" tool.

---

A utility to reduce the amount of memory Firefox or other browsers use is
[Firemin](https://www.rizonesoft.com/downloads/firemin/),
which you could set to run periodically.

[image]